# Anonymous Marker Interface in C#?

Tags: c#, marker-interfaces

I'm wondering if it's possible to locally create marker interfaces in C#, for instance in a foreach loop.

Consider we have gamecomponents that should have their HandleInput- and Update-methods called. The methods are defined in corresponding interfaces, IUpdateable & IInputHandler respectively. We could, of course do a regular foreach loop like this:

```
foreach (var component in Components)
        {
            if (component.Enabled)
                component.Update(gameTime);

            if (component.Litsening)
                component.HandleInput(gameTime, InputManager);
        }
```

However, it would be very neat if there was a way of specifying that the type of the iterationvariables were of a temporary marker interface which is constructed of both IUpdateable & IInputHandler:

```
foreach ((IInputHandler, IUpdateable) component in Components)
        {
            if (component.Enabled)
                component.Update(gameTime);

            if (component.Litsening)
                component.HandleInput(gameTime, InputManager);
        }
```

Would this be possible, and would it be preferable? Personally I would consider it elegant.
// Thanks, Philip Shield

Comment: what is a benefit/meaning of having second case?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 4):

Why not:

```
foreach (var component in Components.OfType<IUpdateable>())        
  if (component.Enabled)
    component.Update(gameTime);

foreach (var component in Components.OfType<IInputHandler>())
  if (component.Litsening)
    component.HandleInput(gameTime, InputManager);
```

Comment: I would even fine-tune it to:
`Components.OfType<IUpdateable>().Where(c=>c.Enabled).ToList().ForEach(c=>Update(gametime));`

Comment: @Avner I'd say that it's a matter of coding style and readability.

Answer (score 1):

C# doesn't allow this sort of construction. Even if it did allow you to create a temporary, anonymous interface, remember that C# is a strongly typed language. So if this IComposite interface existed, your actual component types don't implement it. UpdateableComponent only implements half of IComposite, while your ListeningComponent only implements the other half.

If you're talking about a scenario where your components always implement both interfaces - well, in that case you should create a third interface - not an anonymous on-the-fly construct - that extends both of these to a single composite whole:

```
public interface IGameComponent : IUpdateable, IInputHandler
{ }
```

C# supports multiple inheritance for interfaces, so you can create these composites at compile-time.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
var componentsWeDesire = Components.Where(c => typeof(IInputHandler).IsAssignableFrom(c.GetType()) 
                                               || typeof(IUpdateable).IsAssignableFrom(c.GetType());

foreach(var component in componentsWeDesire)
{
    // ...
}
```